# What are the required packages to run Android Emulator on Ubuntu?

Tags: android, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Intel has a guide [How to Start Intel Hardware-assisted Virtualization (hypervisor) on Linux to Speed-up Intel Android x86 Emulator](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-emulator). It was written for Ubuntu Lucid and up. Some of the packages are not even available anymore.

What are the required packages to run Android Emulator with KVM on recent Ubuntu?

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils ia32-libs-multiarch
```

As far as my understanding goes, only `qemu-kvm` and `libvirt-bin` should only be the two required packages.

```
$ sudo adduser your_user_name kvm
$ sudo adduser your_user_name libvirtd
```

I think a part of above process is also automated now. What are necessary steps to run Android Emulator with KVM on Ubuntu?

Comment: There are many ways to run android on Linux. With kvm you have identified the minimal packages. From there install an android image.

Comment: I know. I just wanted to make sure I got the process right.